# CORS with spring-boot and Vue.js not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using SpringBoot 2.5.6.

I tryto upload file via byte array in the `FileController` class:

```
  @PostMapping("/uploadFileViaStream")
  public JSONObject uploadFile1(@RequestBody byte[] bytes) {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    String fileName = genUUID();

    String fileId = null;
    fileId = fileService.uploadFile("", fileName, inputStream);


    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(1);
    map.put("file", fileId);

    return ZheliResult.ok(map);
  }
```

And add `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")` on the `FileController` class.

The Chrome says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` which is a CORS issue.

Then I delete `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")`, and add a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/*")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT","PATCH", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }

}
```

### Still doesn't work.

Then I delete this and turn to Nginx to configure CORS:

```
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods *;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers *;
```

It does work but after a while the CORS problem appeared again.

Then I configure the SpringCloud Gateway in the bootstrap.yml:

```
gateway:
      globalcors:
        add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]': 
            allowedOrigins: "*" 
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowCredentials: true
```

The Chrome says:

```
 The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

If I change `*` int the Nginx or Gateway to `http://172.20.10.9:8080`, The Chrome says:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://172.20.10.9:8080, http://172.20.10.9:8080', but only one is allowed.
```

So can anyone help me?

Comment: I assume you call /uploadFileViaStream through an ajax call. If that's the case, you can add the _csrf token to your ajax call parameters.

Comment: Honestly saying I'm not sure if it's spring misconfiguration. For some reason your client request doing duplication of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value ('*, *' and 'http://172.20.10.9:8080, http://172.20.10.9:8080'). Check what happens on the client side. You can attach code snaps and request body to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add filter requests and allow CORS to pass. The **HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE** order is importand. Do not neave it out!

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```